# what is wrong with my nested subquery and substr function

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm learning sql and I have this question that I can't solve by myself :

Select name, job, city for employees who do not work in
the same service as their direct supervisor.

I have two tables :

- EMP (NOEMP, NAME, FIRST, NAME, EMPLOI, SUP, HIRING, SAL, COMM, NOSERV)
- SERV (NOSERV SERVICE CITY)

After an analysis of the two tables I can know if a employee is not working in the same city as his supervisor by extracting the second figure of the SUP column.

And here you can read my proposition to solve the question.

```
select e1.nom, e1.prenom, e1.emploi, s1.ville, substr(sup,2,1), e1.noserv`
from emp e1 join
     serv s1
     on e1.noserv = s1.noserv
where e1.nom  in (select distinct e3.nom
                   from emp e3 join
                        emp e4
                        on e3.noserv = e4.noserv
                   where substr(e3.sup,2,1) != e4.noserv
                  );
```

Everything is working well but I have an unexpected output as you can see here in this screen from my laptop.

[output of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVhhW.png)

---

Here the sample of the data :

- [serv table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVhhW.png)
- [emp table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYxe8.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired reesults would help.

Comment: How to find the supervisor of the employee?? Is it as described in fordon's answer?

Comment: Ok. If we find the second digit from SUP then how will we know that they are not in same city? What will be the condition?

Comment: The logic of the answer of Mr gordon is good but I'm facing the same issue, I have an unexpect output ( Dupont jacques) and i also need the city wich is in the serv table so I need to use serv table

Answer (score 0):

This answer makes the following assumptions:

- `sup` is the `empno` of the supervisor
- `noserv` represents the "service"

The second assumption means that you don't need the `serv` table.  It is sufficient to use a `join` and an inequality on `noserv`:

```
select e.*
from emp e join
     emp m
     on m.sup = e.empno and m.noserv <> e.noserv;
```

Comment: Hello, noserv is for the number of the service